# What is the meaning of the rule "it is unspecified whether it is ASSIGNMENT_WORD or WORD" in POSIX shell grammar

Tags: shell, posix

In the POSIX shell grammar at
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10_02

rule 7b contains the statement

```
Otherwise, it is unspecified whether it is ASSIGNMENT_WORD or WORD that is returned.
```

What does this mean?  Does it mean that a compliant shell, for each word token  where the left side of `=` is not empty and not a valid name, for example:

```
,=
```

must classify it  as either `ASSIGNMENT_WORD` or `WORD` but not return an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No: it is *unspecified* which of the two normal results would be returned.  Since it is unspecified, an implementation *could* generate an error (since the specification doesn't mention *what* must happen, merely implies that there's only two choices), but the specification doesn't say that one of those two *must* happen.  It simply doesn't say.

This type of wording is used in cases where someone has in mind a (possibly hypothetical) implementation which could differ from other implementations, and there's no consensus to exclude it from the standard.

The term is in [1.5 Terminology](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap01.html#tag_01_05_08):

unspecified

> Describes the nature of a value or behavior not specified by POSIX.1-2008 which results from use of a valid program construct or valid data input.
>
> The value or behavior may vary among implementations that conform to POSIX.1-2008. *An application should not rely on the existence or validity of the value or behavior.* An application that relies on any particular value or behavior cannot be assured to be portable across conforming implementations.

It's less specific than [*implementation defined*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap01.html#tag_01_05_02):

> Describes a value or behavior that is not defined by POSIX.1-2008 *but is selected by an implementor*. The value or behavior may vary among implementations that conform to POSIX.1-2008. An application should not rely on the existence of the value or behavior. An application that relies on such a value or behavior cannot be assured to be portable across conforming implementations.

Comment: in that case, I have a follow-up question, which I will post as soon as the 40-minute timeout expires.  Thank you very much Thomas I greatly appreciate.

Comment: It does say that _one of those two must happen_ because it doesn't leave any other choice than the token being recognised as a _WORD_ or _ASSIGNMENT_WORD_. If it's a _WORD_, the shell could return an error if the corresponding command is not found. If it's an _ASSIGNMENT_WORD_, the shell could still return an error if it can't assign a variable with such a name.

Answer (score 1):

It says that:

- `foo=bar` is an assignment word
- `=foo` is a word
- `"foo"=bar` or `foo.bar=baz` can be either a *word* or *assignment word*, POSIX doesn't give you any guarantee either way, so you shouldn't use it.
- it seems to imply that `"foo=bar"` (with the quotes) is also unspecified which would suggest that you cannot call (portably) a command with a `=` in its name (other than by using `cmd=foo=bar; "$cmd" ...`), which to me seems to be a bug in the specification as no shell that I know would treat a word with only quoted `=`s as an assignment.

In those unspecified, it does say that *one of those two must happen* because it doesn't leave any other choice than the token being recognised as a *WORD* or _ASSIGNMENT_WORD_.

Now that's only describing the tokenisation stage.

Then according to the grammer, if it's a *WORD*, then that would be the command name. The shell could return an error if the corresponding command is not found.

If it's an *ASSIGNMENT_WORD*, the shell could still return an error if it can't assign a variable with such a name.

In practice,you'll find that some shells allow: `Stéphane=1` or `foo.bar=baz` as assignment, some don't and would then treat those as command names. Some shells would treat them as failing assignment.